# Where is a good source for serious math (wall-size) posters?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education, art

Where is a good source for math wall posters that give glimpses of serious and beautiful mathematics?

I'm a faculty member looking to find some wall posters (e.g. 2 ft x 3 ft) to hang in a handful of display cases around our department. I'd like the posters to be eye-catching and cool (maybe even inspiring!), and also deal with serious mathematics - not be trivial, vague, or snide.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've always found a single expression of the full standard model Lagrangian quite a compellingly complicated picture. Not sure if they make an explanatory poster exactly (I'm sure there's one out there), but here's a favorite coffee cup of mine: http://theory.fnal.gov/jetp/talks/Sabine-FNALWineAndCheese.pdf. EDIT: I do realize that there might be some ambiguity/debatable-ness about the correctness of the way they've written the hermitian conjugate term out there (at least there seems to be elsewhere on the internet), but I am not so well versed in the mathematics of it to judge.

Comment: There are always Escher prints (especially circle limits!) :) I'm not sure if anyone has made (or even has the rights to make) them with math commentary, however.

Answer (score 2):

One source for posters that may fit your description (though I don't know about the size) could be  http://www.ams.org/samplings/mathmoments/mathmoments

Comment: Thanks for the link! Mathematical Moments are good, but not quite what I'm looking for. I'm thinking of something like a huge, compelling picture with just some text giving an idea of what's going on and giving buzzwords to google later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://www.maa.org/programs/students/undergraduate-research/jmm-poster-session/examples-of-outstanding-student-posters

or

http://euler-2007.ch/posters/

or

https://plus.maths.org/content/search/node/POSTER

or google "POSTER MATHEMATICS", ....